# How can I filter a table based upon entered options in an Excel worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have a task list of items that need to be accomplished

| Tasks | Description |
| --- | --- |
| T1 | D1 |
| T2 | D2 |
| T3 | D3 |
| T4 | D4 |

Each of these tasks really only needs to be done when certain conditions are met.

We can attach each of these tasks to conditions in the same row.

| Description | TASKS | Condition1 | Condition2 | Condition3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | T1 | TRUE | TRUE |  |
| D3 | T3 | TRUE |  | TRUE |
| D4 | T4 |  |  | TRUE |

(i'd like to hide these columns eventually)

Now another place in the page I have user entry for if the conditions apply

| List Conditions | Does this Condition Apply |
| --- | --- |
| Condition1 | TRUE |
| Condition2 | FALSE |
| Condition3 | TRUE |

What I want is to be able to filter the Task list dynamically into only activities where the Tasks hit any of the Conditions

For Example, If condition 1, and 3 are true but 2 is false. I would expect to have Tasks T1, T3, and T4 displayed on this list, and task T2 filtered out and not displayed. Task T2 would not display because it requires that Condition 2 be true and T2 is not required for either condition 1 or condition 3.

| Description | Tasks | Condition1 | Condition2 | Condition3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | T1 | TRUE | TRUE |  |
| D3 | T3 | TRUE |  | TRUE |
| D4 | T4 |  |  | TRUE |

What is the easiest way to do this? Would this have to be done via VBA?

Comment: So you don't need all the conditions to be true? I.E. you need a `OR` filter here?

Comment: @urdearboy yes that's correct

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the new `FILTER` function you can create a dynamic table that will apply your `OR` logic to the original table. Here is a sample set up where

- Left table is original data set
- Middle table s the inputs for each criteria
- Right table is the output of the function below (note you have to add headers)

---

Note, you will need to also do one of the following for this to work

1. Instead of leaving cells `BLANK` in first table, add `-` (`or anything that is not FALSE`)
2. Instead of adding `FALSE` as a criteria in the middle table, use `-` (`or anything that is not FALSE`). In my sample I went with this option

The issue is that `BLANK = FALSE` so you need to differentiate the two in one of the sources (not both)

```
J2 = FILTER(A1:E5,(C1:C5=H2)+(D1:D5=H3)+(E1:E5=H4))
```

[image]

*You can remove the `0`'s from output by nesting the formula inside `TEXT` like so: `=TEXT(FILTER(A1:E5,(C1:C5=H2)+(D1:D5=H3)+(E1:E5=H4)),"")`*